# AWS API Gateway proxy and Lambda Integration (Proxy Endpoint Error)

Tags: proxy, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I use API Gateway proxy and Lambda integration.

The problem is Endpoint response.
My Lambda function return this value.

```
{
    "statusCode": 400,
    "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "body": "{\"error\":{\"code\":3,\"message\":\"secretKey is invalid\"}}"
}
```

But, below is API Gateway Method Test logs.

```
Wed Nov 23 08:01:52 UTC 2016 : Endpoint response body before transformations: {"statusCode":400}
```

need help.

Comment: What ist the problem? That the body is missing? Then maybe try it with a 200 to see if the body is then present.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have a Mock integration set on the Integration Request. Can you verify that you're actually pointing at the Lambda function with the 'Use Lambda Proxy Integration' checkbox set?